# Execute a piece of code in my Java web application during startup

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have an web based Java application, where I need to store few data in RAM memory for some kind of operations. I store those data into database also.

Now I need to load those data into RAM memory again when I restart my application(e.g. I am running my application in tomcat and so after re starting tomcat I need to load the data from database to ram memory).

For that I have a function but the issue is how do I detect the application startup event?

I know there is something similar in Java Spring but in my application I am not using Spring.

Any help will be great for me.

Let me know if any more data is necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly: You do have a starting class defined in your application, hook in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how do I detect the application startup event?*

Declare and configure a class implementing `ServletContextListener`.

The [ServletContextListener documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) states :

> Interface for receiving notification events about ServletContext
>   lifecycle changes.
>
> In order to receive these notification events, the implementation
>   class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web
>   application, annotated with WebListener, or registered via one of the
>   addListener methods defined on ServletContext.

You could execute these statements in the `void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method that

> Receives notification that the web application initialization process
>   is starting.

To be usable, the listener should be registered.
Before Servlet 3.0 : declare it in the web.xml.
Since Servlet 3.0 : the previous way or better annotate directly the class with `@WebListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at httpservlet init(ServletConfig) method.

init(...) is called once when the servlet is initialised.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init()

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_03.htm